# symmetric graph with 8 vertices

Tags: graph-theory

I have a simple question I think, but still I'm not sure about its answer.

Is the graph below, symmetric? I mean, if this were a line, and not a graph, for me it's pretty obvious that is symmetric, but as it is a graph, I'm not sure if the line XX' is the symmetric line. If it is the symmetric line, then, this graph will be symmetric, because it has more than one automorphism than the Identity. So, my question is: is XX' the symmetric line of this graph?

By the way: an asymmetric graph would be a graph that its only automorphism is the identity function, and will be symmetric in opposite case

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math.SE! It would be useful for you to edit your question to include what your definition is for a graph to be *symmetric*. (Related: what does *automorphism* mean in this context?) Perhaps by unfolding the definition, you will find the answer to your question. If not, then we will have a better understanding of what you're asking and how to help you.

Comment: It depends, whether a symmetry is expected to preserve the coloring of the nodes or not. Or whether the colors mean anything at all here?

Comment: @Sammy Black already edited!

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen ignore the colors, sorry for that. The colors it has nothing to do in this exercise

Comment: the thing for me is that I found that this graph -if that symmetric line is correct- has 2 automorphisms (the Identity, and the one that you obtain by a reflection around XX'). And since it has more than one automorphism, this graph would be symmetric. But my question is if that line, XX', would be a symmetric line of this graph, because, if it isn't a symmetric line, then I'm wrong

Comment: By your definition in terms of automorphism, you don't need to consider any symmetry line. It is clear that interchange of each pair of nodes having sum 9 is a non-identity automorphism.

Comment: @coffeemath how is that? I don't understand you :s

Comment: An automorphism of a graph is a mapping $f$ from its vertex set $V$ to itself which is a bijection and has the property that for any two vertices $x,y$ there is an edge connecting $x$ to $y$ if and only if there is an edge connecting $f(x)$ to $f(y).$ Given your numbering, consider the map $f(x)=9-x$ and check it has the above properties.

Comment: @coffeemath Now I understand. Thank you so very much!!!

Comment: You are quite welcome. [Note that the above definition of automorphism works for undirected graphs  having no parallel edges.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an uncolored graph, it has the non-trivial automorphism (18)(27)(36)(45), which in this special case can be thought of as mirroring about the drawn line.  It has no other non-trivial automorphisms.

The easiest way to see this is that degree-1 vertices (i.e., leaf vertices) must map to degree-1 vertices.  And in particular, vertex 1 must map to vertex 1 or vertex 8, which determines the rest of the automorphism (since automorphisms preserve edges).

(As a vertex-colored graph, it has no non-trivial automorphisms: no non-trivial isomorphism preserves both edges and vertex colors.)

In general, automorphisms (or symmetries) of graphs will not admit a planar drawing where we can just mirror about a line.  E.g. every permutation of vertices of a complete graph is an automorphism.  We sometimes call non-trivial automorphisms "symmetries" because it's easier to say.